# Delete With PDO Sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Morning, budies. I have an API call to bring me the profilesIds registereds in my websystem. I wanna make delete from my sqlserver table what is not content in my request response.

I do a select with the properties to show me what i have in common with my slqserver table and my response, and i do a delete with remaining.

In theory, it was supposed to work but no.

Have any mistake in sintax plz?

I currently have  have 391 registers in my sql server table and only 389 is comum with my sqlserver table and response call.
When i do a select, bring me only that registers in common, idk wasnt working.

**Select Query** (bring me only 389 registers that i mentioned, is right).

```
    foreach ($result as $indUser => $userInfos){
        $agentId = $userInfos['id'];
        $dhInsert = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        foreach ($userInfos['profileIds'] as $indProfile => $idProfile){

        $sql = "SELECT agentId, profileId
                                FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES
                                WHERE agentId = :agentId
                                AND profileId = :idProfile";

                                  
    $stmt = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":agentId",$agentId,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(":idProfile",$idProfile,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $rows = $stmt->execute();
        
        }
    }
```

**Delete Query** not working.

```
    foreach ($result as $indUser => $userInfos){
        $agentId = $userInfos['id'];
        $dhInsert = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        foreach ($userInfos['profileIds'] as $indProfile => $idProfile){

        $sql = "DELETE FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT agentId, profileId
                                  FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES
                                  WHERE agentId = :agentId
                                  AND profileId = :idProfile)";

                                  
    $stmt = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":agentId",$agentId,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(":idProfile",$idProfile,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $rows = $stmt->execute();
        
        }
    }
```

**Data of table**:

```
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1536989','12345')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1536989','56789')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1536989','99999')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1536874','56789')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1536874','56984')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('7568594','99999')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('8895874','56984')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('8895874','56789')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('8895874','77777')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('8895874','99999')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1235689','56789')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1235689','77777')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1245365','56984')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1245365','56789')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1245365','77777')
insert into testTable (agentId, profileId) values ('1245365','99999')
```

Obs: One agentId can have multiples profileIds, so, agentId is duplicated.
In **data of table**, i show that agentId 1536989 have a profile: 12345, 56789 and 99999. But in request, this agent have only 12345, 56789 profile. So i need delete from table the skill 9999 (f that happens it is successfull).

Comment: I think it should be `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @ADyson Like this?  `$sql = "DELETE FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES WHERE NOT IN (SELECT agentId, profileId FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES WHERE agentId = :agentIdAND profileId = :idProfile)";`  this bring me _Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'_

Comment: Ah sorry wasn't really paying full attention to that, apologies. Barmar's suggestion is better anyway

Comment: Please [edit] and supply sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i solved:

First, in foreach that i use to open the loop of response, i made a array to save this values and transform in querystring:

```
    foreach ($result as $indUser => $userInfos){
        $agentId = $userInfos['id'];
        $dhInsert = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $forDelete[] = array(
            'agentIdForDelete' => "'".$agentId."'",
            'profileIdForDelete' => "'".implode("','",$userInfos['profileIds'])."'",

        );
```

After, i print `$forDelete` and get this response:
[Responsejson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD3YF.png)

Then i set a loop to iterate index and execute my delete query:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($forDelete); $i++){

        $agentIdForDelete = $forDelete[$i]['agentIdForDelete'];
        $profileIdForDelete = $forDelete[$i]['profileIdForDelete'];
    

        $sql = "DELETE FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES
                WHERE agentId = $agentIdForDelete AND profileId NOT IN ($profileIdForDelete)";

        $stmt = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
```

That was the way I found to solve the problem. If anyone has another suggestion, i'm available :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the subquery.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM LIVEPERSON_USERPROFILES
        WHERE agentId = :agentId AND profileId <> :idProfile)";
```

Comment: This way deleted all rows hahhahaha

Comment: It should delete all rows except the ones with that agentId and profileId.

Comment: So it should delete the 2 rows that were NOT returned by the `SELECT` query.

Comment: Yes, the logic is right, but I need it for another purpose. I need it to exclude only those that are not in the table. Example, I have agentId 12345 with profileId 5678 and 15975 in the table. In my request it returns that agentId 12345 has only profileId 5678, so it is to delete 15975.

Comment: I've updated the answer, is that what you want?

Comment: mm, partially. Because the agentdId can have more than one profileId, then it repeats the agentId in the table. In this query he deletes and leaves the agentId unique. I believe that as he does one by one, he leaves only the last profileId consulted and excludes the others. With this query I got 262 rows. We are getting close !!!!

Comment: Please update the question, show some sample data, sample values for the variables, and the desired result.

Comment: I've update the question. Need any more data?

Comment: I don't understand **But in request, this agent have only 12345, 56789 profile**. How can there be two profiles in the request? There's just one `$idProfile`

Comment: This `$idProfile` comes from a foreach. So when I insert it into the table, it inserts the agentId of each return of the profileId. So if I have an agentId with 3 profilesIds, it will repeat the agentId for each profileId it has.

Comment: You can't do the delete in that loop, since each iteration only knows about one profile at a time. You have to do the delete outside the loop, so you can list all the profile IDs: `WHERE agentId = :agentId and profileId NOT IN (:idProfile1, :idProfile2, ...)`

Comment: Dude, i have no idea how i'll do this. Can u help me plx?

Comment: It's more complicated because you're working with multiple agent ID and multiple profile ID. I need to finish my real work before I can help you.